# read/write /dev/ttySDIO0 like a file?

Tags: android

Need to read/write to a tty SDIO device in an user space program in using JNI in Android.
Is it possible to open the device (/dev/ttySDIO0) using fopen and read/write as a normal file?

From the terminal apps it is possible to do cat/echo to it. However I am looking for a approach which can be used in a program.

I don't see the .read operation defined in the SDIO UART driver.

Thank you.

EDIT: I am using Android Dev Phone 1 which has Android 1.6 (Linux Kernel Version 2.6.29).

Comment: This question is better suited for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Yes, after posting the question I got the same impression. Is there anyway I can use the same question and continue it at StackOverflow, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: No. You have to repost from scratch. You can open the question for edit to copy the source, however!

Comment: Apparently it *is* possible. Go figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I browsed the SDIO driver source from the latest Linux Kernel Version 2.6.34. It has added file_operations structure which has .read operation listed. I realized I need to upgrade the Android to resolve the issue.

Thank you all for your time, effort and answers.